# Swift UIPageController not working properly with scroll transition

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I am making a Time Schedule app for my school and wanted to scroll through the days of the week. I made one View Controller for each day and connected them up to a UIPageViewController. I sat the transition style to "Scroll" and navigation to "Horisontal", but the view controllers did not render properly! However if I set the Navigation to "Vertical" or transition style to "Page Curl" it works fine!

[Here is a gif of how it looks with the scroll transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhUFX.gif)

[And here is a gif of how it looks with the page curl transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icWcs.gif)

So i am wondering, why it looks so weird. And how to fix it?

Here is some of my code for the PageViewController:

```
        let Sider = ["Mandag", "Tysdag", "Onsdag", "Torsdag", "Fredag"]

        override func viewDidLoad() {     
            self.delegate = self
            self.dataSource = self 
        }

        override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

            let cal = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            let date = Date()
            let Vekedag = cal.component(.weekday, from: date)

            if Vekedag == 7 || Vekedag == 1 {
                print("Da e helg!!")
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Fredag") as UIViewController!
                setViewControllers([vc!],
                                   direction: .forward,
                                   animated: true,
                                   completion: nil)

            }else if Vekedag == 2{
            let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Mandag") as UIViewController!
                setViewControllers([vc!],
                direction: .forward,
                animated: true,
                completion: nil)

            }else if Vekedag == 3{
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Tysdag") as UIViewController!
                setViewControllers([vc!],
                                   direction: .forward,
                                   animated: true,
                                   completion: nil)

            }else if Vekedag == 4{
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Onsdag") as UIViewController!
                setViewControllers([vc!],
                                   direction: .forward,
                                   animated: true,
                                   completion: nil)

            }else if Vekedag == 5{
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Torsdag") as UIViewController!
                setViewControllers([vc!],
                                   direction: .forward,
                                   animated: true,
                                   completion: nil)
            }else if Vekedag == 6{
                let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Fredag") as UIViewController!
                setViewControllers([vc!],
                                   direction: .forward,
                                   animated: true,
                                   completion: nil)
            }
        }

 func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let identifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier {
            if let index = Sider.index(of: identifier) {
                if index > 0 {
                    return self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Sider[index-1])
                }
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? { 
            if let identifier = viewController.restorationIdentifier {
                if let index = Sider.index(of: identifier) {
                    if index < Sider.count - 1 {
                        return self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Sider[index+1])
                    }
                }
            }
            return nil
        }

        func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

            return Sider.count
        }

        func presentationIndex(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {

            if let identifier = viewControllers?.first?.restorationIdentifier {
                if let index = Sider.index(of: identifier) {
                    return index
                }
            }
            return 0
        }
```